# Azure App Service "Scale Out" -- Instances Running Different App Versions?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, azure-appservice

I have a Dotnet 6 Web Application running on a Windows-based Azure App Service. As traffic grew, I took the recommendation to "scale-out" the app service to two instances. My deployments are done via a simple GitHub action and publish profile.

I've noticed that, by hitting the root API endpoint in which I return the build and server of the running API, that each of the two servers is running a different version of the code. When it builds and deploys next time, only one server reflects the newer version.

```
- name: Azure WebApp
  uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2.2.3
  with:
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREWEBAPPPUBLISHPROFILE }}
    app-name: esferas-app
    slot-name: staging
    package: ./artifacts/web
```

Is there something I'm missing? I couldn't find anything scouring the Azure or the GitHub Actions documentation for anything special required for scaling out on deploys.

Comment: Are you by any chance hitting the endpoint of the staging slot instead of hitting another instance?

Comment: How are you testing? Are you killing one server and letting the load balancer take you to the other one?

Comment: @PeterBons - It's replicated with both slots; staging had two different versions and the production slot had two different versions.

Comment: @misha130 - I have an /api endpoint that returns the app name, server name, environment, and compiled version that is added during CI build. I can navigate to that endpoint and hit 'refresh' a handful of times and see the different instances and versions I'm load balanced to.

Comment: Looks like it could be related to -ARR Affinity cookies or Slot-specific app settings (slot sticky), Application Initialization or Local cache (if enabled).

1. Application Initialization ensures that your app instances have fully started before they are added to start serving requests.           
2.Azure WebApps by default have ARR Affinity cookie enabled, this cookie pairs a client request to a specific server.    
3.If auto swap is enabled with custom warm-up, trigger Application Initiation by making an HTTP request to the application root ("/") on each instance of the source slot.

Comment: 4.If local cache is enabled, trigger local cache initialization by making an HTTP request to the application root ("/") on each instance of the source slot. Wait until each instance returns any HTTP response. Local cache initialization causes another restart on each instance.

Comment: 5. Review the warm-up behaviour - you can also customize the warm-up behavior with one or both of the following app settings:
WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH: The path to ping over HTTP to warm up your site. Add this app setting by specifying a custom path that begins with a slash as the value. An example is /statuscheck. The default value is /.

Comment: @MattGWagner, when you get a chance, could you please confirm if it's isolated to- ARR Affinity cookies or/ Slot-specific app settings (slot sticky), Application Initialization or Local cache?

Comment: Thanks, @AjayKumar-MSFT! For this app, ARR affinitity is off -- for context, it's a Blazor Server app with the Azure SignalR service running. It does not have a warm-up behavior configured, and it's happening both on the prod and staging slots. I have noticed that if I trigger a manual App Service restart, the versions match afterwards, which makes me think it might be a DLL locked on one server during the deploy?

Comment: MattGWagner,   Apologies for the delay! To help perform deeper investigation on this, for which we need webapp and subscription details. So, I have followed-up with you privately on this on your Q&A thread.

Comment: Did you figure out the cause?